# How to retrieve cellForRow(at:) when tableview isn't visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, unit-testing

I've created a class that contains all UITableView protocol methods. I'm using it successfully in a ViewController that has a tableview on its scene.

The advantage to having all of the tableview code in a different class is that I should be able to unit test tableview methods. The problem I'm running into is that when I call `cellForRow(at:)`, it returns a `nil` cell.

I can put a breakpoint in the tableview class's `cellForRow(at:)` and see just before it `return cell` that the cell is valid. Once I leave `cellForRow(at:)` and go back into the unit test, the returned cell is nil.

This happens because none of the cells are visible. This thread [ [Table view's `cellForRow(at:)` is `nil` in Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466837/table-views-cellforrowat-is-nil-in-unit-test) ] hits on the problem but not solution for this specific case.

Is there some way to return a cell from `cellForRow(at:)` when the tableview/cells are not visible?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916900/selecting-all-the-items-in-uicollectionview-ios-even-the-cells-that-are-not-vis/40260088#40260088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, `UITableView.cellForRow(at:)` method doesn't return a cell if it's not visible at that moment.

In the meanwhile why not use the data-source of the UITableView and call [`UITableViewDataSource.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) ? I think it does exactly what you need and returns cells disregarding the actual `UITableView` position.

Comment: There is no `myTableViewClass.UITableViewDataSource.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

Comment: @4thSpace, sure, this is the method of protocol, that should be implemented to provide your `UITableView` with data. Usually a `UIViewController`, which contains the `UITableView` implements these methods, but it might be any other class that is set as [dataSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614955-datasource) delegate for your UITableView.

Comment: I already have the tableView methods implemented into my class, which is an NSObject.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understood the idea. Did you implement your own class of the UITableView? Where does it take data from?

Comment: Yes - that's what I mentioned in the OP. The data comes from an array in the tableView class.

Comment: Yep, I mean, you use a separate NSObject as the data source, right? So you are able to call its methods within your unit tests, aren't you?

Comment: Yes - the datasource is in the separate NSObject. That class also has both tableView protocols, which means it must also have the related tableView methods.  Yes - I can call the tableView methods in the test. What I'm finding out though is that I need to rework the custom cell since it uses IBOutlets.

Comment: Thank you @AleksandrMedvedev for the tip! I am using `let cell = self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as! CustomTableViewCell` and it is working like gorgeous!

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell will process appearance calculation in the delegate `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, so you may want get the cell it doesn’t definite.

I have met this question recently, and my solution is following:

Definite a global variable (2D-Array) in this or another file:

```
class ThisTableCell
{
static var cells = [UITableViewCell](repeating: [UITableViewCell](repeating: UITableViewCell(), count: sectionCount), count: rowCount)
}
```

And then add

```
ThisTableCell.cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = cell
```

in that delegate.
And you can type `ThisTableCell.cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` to get current Cell.